# What runs in the body of Pokemons?

Tags: pokemon

When people get hurt blood comes out.
But nothing happens when *Pokemons* get hurt. Do they have blood running in their body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That really depends on the pokemon....

For instance bug pokemon do not really have blood, but some form of juices and such...

Another example of a Pokemon that has something similar to blood is Cacturne...

From the Pokemon Wikia :

> Cacturne is a nocturnal Pokémon that rarely moves during the day,
>   which allows it to hold moisture. At night, it searches for prey or
>   follows travelers until they become exhausted. It has lived in deserts
>   for so long that its blood has transformed into sand. With its thorny
>   arms, it is able to use its former signature move, Needle Arm.

It's also worth it to note that quite a number of Pokemon are similar to animals in the real world so the make up of the inner body would be similar...

For instance some Pokedex entries include stuff about the heart, like Spoink.

> Spoink is a gray, pig-like Pokémon. It has dark, circular eyes, a
>   large gray nose, and small ears. It has stubby arms and possesses no
>   hind legs. Motion is achieved by bouncing on its spring-like tail. The
>   bouncing has a vital function, in that it keeps its heart beating.

The only types of Pokemon that would never really have blood and such are the ones that are Ghost-type Pokemon and a few others like Rock Type.  Though perhaps the Ghost Type pokemon would be ectoplasm, which isn't really blood, but it's hard to say considering in the game you can't hit them with normal physical attacks...

Also there's no blood in the anime because it's a Children's show.